# Double slash // in paths - can I use single slash?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I have a VS template with something like

```
string mypath = "C:\\custom\\file.jpg";
```

I'd like to make the C:\custom\ part with a template substitution parameter $userpath$. Is there any way I can avoid using double slashes?

What I'd like to write is:

```
string mypath = SOMETHING("C:\custom\file.jpg")
```

that doesn't get escaped with \c and \f and form a valid path. Is it possible?

Comment: You could look at raw string literals, or you could just use a forward slash and have it be a *little* more portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For paths you should be able to use a single *forward* slash as a separator:

```
std::string mypath = "c:/custom/file.jpg";
```

Answer (score 5):

Try a raw string literal:

```
string mypath = R"(C:\custom\file.jpg)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get used of double backslash character, because in c++ all parser and compiler understand that. and if your VS template `\\`  doublebackslash produce a `\` single backslash, use 4 backslash `\\\\` to produce `\\` doublebackslash correctly.

Comment: It just doesn't work. For I am using the one slash, it thinks that I am escaping the next character. It's okay, so I am using the double slash, a-a-and… I am gettin the double slash! Not single, but the double! Just insane…